# Cloudant warehouse, deleted documents are not synced

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, dashdb, cloudant-sdp

I went through documentation on Cloudant warehouse but not able to find how are deleted documents synced. My requirement is that, just as in Cloudant replication, I would want documents deleted in Cloudant to also be deleted in dash DB. But I do not see that happening. How do I enable that?

Answer (score 0):

Try synchronizing it again by restarting the warehouse from Cloudant dashboard.

Comment: thanks RiyaMRoy, but clearly that's not a practical solution!

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to use Data Connect service in IBM Bluemix